# Realistic / Semirealistic thermal energy transfer algorithm using cellular automata?

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a cellular automata program. It has the following features:

- Ability to control each cell individually - each cell has its own "intelligence";
- Ability for each cell to get access to the grid, subsequently being able to get any cell instance on the grid given its coordinates;
- Each cell has various attributes, the relevant ones being `temp` and `tempIsolation`

I am using Unity for this project, calling the function every second (`1/60` iterations per frame, I'm not using `Time.deltaTime`, as I wanted a fixed value that would return an integer value every second). I am also running the code that ensures this constance pace in `fixedUpdate`, then calling an external function with the name of `TemperaturePhysicsIteration`

```
void Block.TemperaturePhysicsIteration()
```

In the code each cell is represented as a GameObject with a `Block` class attached to it. Each GameObject is then stored on a 2D `GameObject` array (in a different class, stored in an empty `GameObject` in the scene to make sure every cell has access to the same world), called `world`.

The goal of the program is to be a heat transfer simulation.  I have created two `for` loops to get all 8 cells around the reference cell, so heat transfers can occur.

I've been trying to find an algorithm to transfer the thermal energy using the current temperature, the other block's temperature, and the respective thermal isolation values (0 - 100, 0 not isolating energy at all (which I don't usually use), and 100 completely isolating thermal energy (the block itself can be influenced by temperature, but it can't transfer any more thermal energy since its `tempIsolation` value is 100)), but I have failed.

Here's my code:

```cs
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(world.i > 1000)
        {
            world.i = 0;
        }
        if(world.i % 2 == 0)
        {
            TemperaturePhysicsIteration();
        }

        world.i += 1f/60f * world.refreshInterval;

        if (world.thermalCamera == true && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.T))
        {
            thisBlock.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(Color.red.r, Color.red.g, Color.red.b, (getAttribute("temp").value / 1000) * 256);
        }
        else
        {
            thisBlock.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
        }
    }

    public void TemperaturePhysicsIteration()
    {
        Vector2Int v = new Vector2Int((int)gameObject.transform.position.x, (int)gameObject.transform.position.y);
        for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
            {
                if (world.checkBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y))
                {
                    // Other block's temperature -> world.getBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y).GetComponent<Block>().getAttribute("temp").value
                    // Temperature -> getAttribute("temp").value
                    // Other block's temperature isolation -> world.getBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y).GetComponent<Block>().getAttribute("tempIsolation").value
                    // Temperature Isolation -> getAttribute("tempIsolation").value

                    //Current failed attempt

                    changeAttributeValue("temp", getAttribute("temp").value + ((world.getBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y).GetComponent<Block>().getAttribute("temp").value / 2f) / (1f / (getAttribute("tempIsolation").value / 100f))));


                    //Other failed attempts


                    //world.getBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y).GetComponent<Block>().changeAttributeValue("temp", 
                    //((getAttribute("temp").value * (100 - (world.getBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y).GetComponent<Block>().getAttribute("tempIsolation").value)) / 100) + world.getBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y).GetComponent<Block>().getAttribute("temp").value) / 2);
                    //world.getBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y).GetComponent<Block>().changeAttributeValue("temp", ((getAttribute("temp").value * (100 / getAttribute("tempIsolation").value)) + world.getBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y).GetComponent<Block>().getAttribute("temp").value) / 2);
                   //changeAttributeValue("temp", ((world.getBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y).GetComponent<Block>().getAttribute("temp").value - (world.getBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y).GetComponent<Block>().getAttribute("tempIsolation").value / 100) * world.getBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y).GetComponent<Block>().getAttribute("temp").value) + (getAttribute("temp").value - (getAttribute("tempIsolation").value / 100) * getAttribute("temp").value)) / (2 - (world.getBlock(v.x + x, v.y + y).GetComponent<Block>().getAttribute("tempIsolation").value / 100) * 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: stackoverflow is for specific coding issues, and I don't see a clear well defined problem with your code. It's unclear if there is a coding problem or if it's an algorithm problem. It may be better to ask about your algorithm first on a science site, and then if your code is giving unexpected results ask a specific question about that here.

Comment: P.S. Here's a list of science Stack Exchange websites for reference: https://stackexchange.com/sites#science

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I know little of correct simulation of heat transfer. If you want this for anything serious, you should investigate Finite Element Analysis (FEA) or Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD), since these seem to be the dominating methods.

But I might provide some hints that might be useful:

You might want to use a separate data structure instead of using game-objects directly. This will probably significantly help performance. A simple multidimensional array, `double[,]`, might be sufficient.

Also, you probably want to do the simulation in two steps,

1. Compute a new temperature for each node
2. Replace the current temperature with the new temperature

Otherwise the result will depend on the order nodes are processed in, and that is probably not what you want.

Perhaps something like this pseudo code:

```
var deltaTemperature = 0;
Foreach(var neighborTemperature in NeighboringBlocks){
    var diff = neighborTemperature - currentTemperature;
    var heatTransfer = diff * isolationValue;
    var deltaTemperature += heatTransfer * 1/8d; // assuming 8 neighbors
}
var newTemperature = currentTemperature - deltaTemperature;
```

Comment: Should be `var deltaTemperature += heatTransfer * 1/8d;` (+= instead of =)